# How to use Clang's CUDA compiler?

Tags: c++, cuda, clang++

I am on Ubuntu 17.10. I installed the CUDA 9.1 SDK from NVIDIA.

This is what I tried:

```
~/GrinGoldMiner/src/Cudacka$ clang++-5.0 -Wl,--cuda-path=/usr/local/cuda-9.1 kernel.cu
clang: error: cannot find libdevice for sm_20. Provide path to different CUDA installation via --cuda-path, or pass -nocudalib to build without linking with libdevice.
clang: error: cannot find CUDA installation.  Provide its path via --cuda-path, or pass -nocudainc to build without CUDA includes.
clang: error: cannot find CUDA installation.  Provide its path via --cuda-path, or pass -nocudainc to build without CUDA includes.
```

Obviously it doesn't work. It seems like the linker flags are not getting passed. How can I pass them correctly?

Comment: It looks like clang is trying to compile for a GPU architecture which your CUDA version doesn't support

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems `clang++-5.0` does not support CUDA 9.X ...

`clang++` is able to compile CUDA kernels with CUDA 8.0:

```
$ clang++-5.0 -O0 -g --cuda-gpu-arch=sm_50 --cuda-path=/usr/local/cuda-8.0 -o t1 t1.cu -L/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64 -lcudart
```

But when using CUDA 9.X I get the same error as you:

```
$ clang++-5.0 --cuda-gpu-arch=sm_50 --cuda-path=/usr/local/cuda-9.0 -o t1 t1.cu -L/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64 -lcudart
clang: error: cannot find libdevice for sm_50. Provide path to different CUDA installation via --cuda-path, or pass -nocudalib to build without linking with libdevice.
```

They added support for Volta (sm_70) and CUDA 9.0 in this commit: [6d4cb40](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/commit/6d4cb407f117d080e04cf6b8ca200ee01c7b502f). 
In 2017, this was only available on `master` branch, and you would have confirmed it like this:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang.git 
$ cd clang/ 
$ git branch --contains 6d4cb40
* master

$ git checkout release_50
Branch release_50 set up to track remote branch release_50 from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'release_50'
$ git log | grep 6d4cb40
$ (output was empty)
```

Note that clang (7.0.0, released September 2018) supports CUDA 7.0 through 9.2.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to build the [GrinGoldMiner](https://github.com/mozkomor/GrinGoldMiner)'s Cudacka under Ubuntu 17.10, and all I had to do was:

```
make
```

This generated two commands on my machine (after some cleanup):

```
/usr/local/cuda-9.1/bin/nvcc -ccbin g++ -m64 -Xcompiler -fpermissive -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_37,code=sm_37 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 -gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 -gencode arch=compute_60,code=sm_60 -gencode arch=compute_61,code=sm_61 -gencode arch=compute_70,code=sm_70 -gencode arch=compute_70,code=compute_70 -o cudacka.o -c kernel.cu
/usr/local/cuda-9.1/bin/nvcc -ccbin g++ -m64 -Xcompiler -fpermissive -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_37,code=sm_37 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 -gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 -gencode arch=compute_60,code=sm_60 -gencode arch=compute_61,code=sm_61 -gencode arch=compute_70,code=sm_70 -gencode arch=compute_70,code=compute_70 -o Cudacka.exe cudacka.o
```

And they finished successfully generating executable `Cudacka.exe`.

If you are interested specifically in clang:

When I tried to replace `g++` with `clang++-5.0`, I got this error:

```
nvcc fatal   : The version ('50000') of the host compiler ('clang') is not supported
```

If I use `-std=c++11 -ccbin clang++` instead of `-ccbin g++`, I get this error:

```
kernel.cu(397): error: explicit instantiation definition directive for __global__ functions with clang host compiler is not yet supported
```

So, I doubt that you can use clang to compile that code for Ubuntu.